# Localisation of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, localization

I’m not sure exactly about the conditions needed for a subset $S$ to localise a ring $R$. I know $S$ has to be multiplicative. But does $S$ also have to be a subset of the non-zero divisors of $R$ or does it have to be a subset of the group of units of $R$?

I can’t find a clear answer.

Comment: It can be any multiplicative set, but if it contains zero divisors, the behavior might not be what you initially expect. For instance, if $S$ contains a nilpotent element, then the localized ring is the zero ring.

Comment: But $S$ doesn't need to be a subset of units: localization *creates* units from elements of $S$.

Comment: Why does nilpotent element imply that @CaptainLama

Comment: I thought S couldn’t contain zero divisors or else the product of two fractions in the localised rings could have a zero as denominator possibly.

Comment: You're right, but it turns out it's ok to divide by $0$... exactly in the zero ring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Localisation is defined for any commutative ring with identity $R$, and for any multiplicatively closed subset $S \subset R$: $1 \in S$ and $s,t \in S$ implies $st \in S$.

In fact the inclusion homomorphism $R \rightarrow S^{-1}R$ is injective if and only if $S$ contains no zero divisiors, and $S^{-1}R = 0$ if and only if $S$ contains $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Classical localization can be extended to noncommutative rings using the [Ore conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore_condition).  They are a set of sufficient conditions to guarantee that the classical construction works, at least on one side.

That is if you have a subset $S$ of a ring $R$ that is

1. Multiplicatively closed;
2. satisfies $aS\cap sR\neq \emptyset$ for every $s\in S$ and $a\in R$;
3. If $s\in S$ and $a\in R$ and $sa=0$, there exists a $u\in S$ such that $au=0$.

When $R$ is commutative the second and third conditions are automatically satisfied for any nonempty multiplicative set.

> does  also have to be a subset of the non-zero divisors of

No, for example consider the ring $R=F[x,y]/(xy)$, for which the nonnegative powers of $x$ (in the quotient) form a multiplicative set entirely of zero divisors.  The thing is that some elements will collapse to zero: for example $y=\frac{y}{1}=\frac{xy}{x}=\frac 0 x=0$ ($x,y,1$ the images in $R$ of the original $x,y,1$ in $F[x,y]$.)  If you have two things that annihilate each other in the multiplicative set, then you have $0$ in there too and that makes everything collapse.

The thing is that the collection of (left and right) regular elements of a ring is automatically multiplicatively closed, so they make a convenient multiplicative subset.

> or does it have to be a subset of the group of units of ?

You can, but it is more interesting to include things that aren't units in the multiplicative set, because they *become* units in the localization.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that is "forbidden" is that $0\in S$ or otherwise the localized ring is the $0$-ring. Also you better have $1\in S$ (or to be precise in the saturation of $S$) or else the canonical map
$$
\phi:A\longrightarrow S^{-1}A,\qquad \phi(a)=\frac a1
$$
is not defined.

Of course $S$ can contain zero-divisors, but be aware that when $A$ is not a domain the equivalence relation on $A\times S$ that leads to $S^{-1}A$ by taking quotient is
$$
(a,s)\sim(a',s')\Longleftrightarrow\text{$t(as'-a's)=0$ for some $t\in S$}.
$$
This is forced because if you ask just that $as'-a's=0$ (like when one constructs the field of fractions of a domain) you don't get a transitive relation.

It is now straightforward to check that if $t\in S$ is a zero-divisor then $\phi(t)=0$.

Comment: There is no reason to say $0\in S$ is "forbidden"; the zero ring is a perfectly good ring, and all of the usual theory of localization still works in that case.

Comment: @EricWofsey. .... and that's exactly the reason why I wrote  *it is "forbidden"* (with quotes) instead of *it is forbidden* (without quotes). A student needs to realize that including $0$ in a multiplicative part leads to a somewhat degenerate situation.